# How to show current time in u-boot

Tags: c, time, u-boot

I'm trying to display current time in the bootloader to calculate how much a function takes to be executed. I used the time.h library but it doesn't work perfectly.
any idea ?
used code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
time_t t;
time(&t);
printf("\before watchdog init: %s", ctime(&t));
```

error: implicit declaration of function 'time' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

error: implicit declaration of function 'ctime' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

Comment: Posting the code would help.

Comment: You can't call `time` and `printf` outside functions like that.  Put it in one and it'll work. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/63Ke9jra7). Sidenote: Do you really want a `\b` (bell) before `efore`?

Comment: I called it inside a function. actually the time.h library doesn't contain the mentioned functions

Comment: maybe sys/time.h?

Comment: it doesn't exist in bootloader ( u-boot )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: U-Boot is not an ordinary user environment where you can expect to call any of the C library routines. There simply is no standard C library built with U-Boot. So there is no **time()** or **ctime()** routines unless you write them yourself.  U-Boot does support a few RTC chips, so if you're lucky that's one less driver to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for any C code to display the current time. Just execute the shell command `date`.

To update the RTC time via the network use the `sntp` command. If your board does not have a real time clock, you can emulate it with configuration setting CONFIG_RTC_EMULATION=y.

If you still need a solution in C, look at the code in cmd/date.c:

```
                struct rtc_time tm;
                int rcode = 0;
                rcode = dm_rtc_get(dev, &tm);
                if (rcode) {
                        puts("## Get date failed\n");
                        break;
                }   

                printf ("Date: %4d-%02d-%02d Time: %2d:%02d:%02d\n",
                        tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_mday,
                        tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
```